# How to link pthread_win32 for gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, dll

I read the [README](ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32/prebuilt-dll-2-9-1-release/README) for the pthreads_win32 library, and because I'm using MinGW there was a section that says how to run your program with the library which says:

> If you're using pthreadGC.dll:
>
> With the three header files, pthreadGC.dll and libpthreadGC.a in the
>   same directory as your application myapp.c, you could compile, link
>   and run myapp.c under Mingw32 as follows:
>
> gcc -o myapp.exe myapp.c -I. -L. -lpthreadGC

I downloaded all three of the header files, the two other ones (they're actually called pthreadGC2.dll and libpthreadGC2.a in this release) and put them all in my current directory.

Now if I compile with this line, using no pthread functions except for the line that includes the pthread library, there are no errors:

gcc -o project1.exe project1.c -I. -L. -lpthreadGC2

But if I try to actually use any of the functions I get this when compiling using the same line.

C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4ftpKo.o:project1.c:(.text+0x27): undefine
    d reference to `_imp__pthread_exit'
    C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4ftpKo.o:project1.c:(.text+0xe0): undefine
    d reference`enter code here`to`_imp__pthread_create'
    C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4ftpKo.o:project1.c:(.text+0x161): undefin
    ed reference to `_imp__pthread_exit'
    c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\M
    ichael\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4ftpKo.o: bad reloc address 0x20 in section`.eh_fra
    me'
    c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link
     failed: Invalid operation
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Any ideas what this could be? I'm not that familiar with libraries in C.